# How to invalidate any ISP cache when querying a web service from a mobile?

Tags: caching, networking, mobile

Some (rogue) ISPs may implement caching on their mobile network in order to reduce traffic on their connections. Some even don't tell their users.

Is there any standard way to defeat all caching mechanism in such cases and get sure to get fresh data when issuing a request on a web server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most common approach is to include a unique timestamp.

Comment: As an additional useless get param for instance ?

Comment: Yes, that is the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> POST requests usually travel unaltered and are not cached, but there's
>   a drawback to that when you need to investigate server logs and cannot
>   see query string params in the log. Another popular cache busting
>   technique is to append a random query string param to each request,
>   like ?ts=${timestamp}, which forces proxy servers to fetch content
>   from the origin servers.
>
> In my opinion the best solution for that problems is to use SSL
>   whenever possible. This makes it impossible for ISPs to tamper with
>   requests and it is safe to assume that the communication is happening
>   directly between client and server (and it is possible to detect when
>   someone tries to hijack the encrypted connection).

Credit to Filip Wasilewski for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: This is a nice response. Thanks @Moritz. It should be completed with the technique pointed at by Dark Falcon : add a dummy param to a get request.